# Finding the total quantity and total price sold of a specific product in a given day

Tags: woocommerce

I am running a WordPress site and using the woocommerce plugin. I would like to get a list of all products that were sold in a given day, along with how many of each item and the total price for that day.

Answer (score 0):

First get all the orders by using `get_posts` method you can pass the date in date query param and than in the loop you can use `WC_Order($order->ID)` to get order details and `get_items()` to get all products of particular order.

```
$orders = get_posts( array (
                            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
                            'date_query' => array(
                                array(
                                        'year'  => date('Y'),
                                        'month' => date('m'),
                                        'day'   => date('d'),
                                      )          ),
                          ) 
                 );
             foreach ($orders as $order)
            {
                $order_wc = new WC_Order( $order->ID );
                $products = $order_wc->get_items();
                var_dump($order);
                var_dump($products);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks , i need product list with how many quantity is ordered of that product in a day ,also total price of according to quantity like "A"product is ordered by 3 customers and quantity is 1kg by each customer and price is 10 Rs. The result should be total quantity =  3kg in a day  and total  price is = 30Rs

Comment: did you tried the above solution. it will give you all the order products on that particular day and you can count the quantity and price

Comment: yes i tried and it is displaying all the ordered and price. but how can i count that individual product is ordered nth times.i mean how can i count the total quantity of each product if this product is ordered by 2or 3 customers.did you understand my requirement if you have any question please let me know